# How to show specific control in fullscreen mode UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I write an YouTube client for UWP platform and now I'm stuck on fullscreen mode. I've written own video player based on `MediaElement` with [image: separate independent media controls].

And when I go to fullscreen I get this

[image: this].

So in that case I need to show in fullscreen mode the whole video player control. But I don't know how exactly I supposed to do this. I've already tried this:

```
private async void fullscreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fullScreen)
        {
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
            mainPageBackup = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage;
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content = this;
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content = mainPageBackup;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();` should be sufficient. Also - you do not update the `fullScreen` variable.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Yeah, at first I really forgot to update`fullScreen` variable. But in this case it doesn't matter.
`ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode()` isn't enough because it sets the whole application to go to fullscreen mode as it is but I also need to open video player control in fullscreen

Comment: so just hide any other elements...

Comment: The below answer could make the `MediaPlayerElement` display with full screen. And play button, next button will show in the bottom, I do not know which control you want show in the fullscreen?

Comment: @Alamakanambra actually you are right. It's really solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's a one simple solution. Thanks to Alamakanambra's comment (below the question). I just hide everything that I don't need when I go to fullscreen.
I've created an event and get `MainPage` and `VideoPage` subscribed to it.

```
public event EventHandler SetFullscreen;

private async void fullscreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetFullscreen.Invoke(this, null);
    if (!fullScreen)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
        mainPageBackup = (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as MainPage;
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content = this;
    }
    else
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();
        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content = mainPageBackup;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [IsFullWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.isfullwindow) property to true;

```
private void OnFullScreenButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    videoSource.IsFullWindow = true;
}
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work because I need to see not only video but also controls in fullscreen mode