# UWP Replace MainView with FullScreen Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

In my App I have a MainView (Red) that consists of a MainMenu and a Frame (Blue)
(see picture)

[image: MainView and Frame]

The MainMenu should be visible in most Pages. The Frame is replaced by the different pages.

```
<Page 
<!--[properties (shortened)...]-->

    <!-- This is the MainMenu -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Name="MainMenu"
          Visibility="{x:Bind MenuVisibility}"
          Background="#1F3d7A"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

          <!--[content (shortened)...]-->

    </Grid>

    <!-- This is the Frame to display the different pages -->
    <Frame Grid.Row="1"
           x:Name="Frame"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           Grid.Column="0">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
    <!--[more content (shortened)...]-->
</Page>
```

However, in some pages I do not want the MainMenu to be visible. Instead, the Frame should be in fullscreen mode.

In another thread someone achieved this with the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865008/how-to-show-specific-control-in-fullscreen-mode-uwp?answertab=active#tab-top).

I copied the code and it works.
Unfortunately, it leads to some bugs. For example, when my Frame contains a MediaElement, the controls disappear when making the frame fullscreen.

Is there another solution to making the MainMenu disappear or making the inner Frame go fullscreen and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

> However, in some pages I do not want the MainMenu to be visible. Instead, the Frame should be in fullscreen mode.

For your scenario, you need modify the `fullscreen` method. **Note**: `Page` class contains Frame field, please avoid set Frame name for `Frame`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (!fullScreen)
    {
        mainPageBackup = this.Frame;
        Window.Current.Content = MyFrame;     
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();              
        fullScreen = true;
    }
    else
    {          
        Window.Current.Content = mainPageBackup;                  
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();            
        fullScreen = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a custom transport control. You should create a `CustomMediaTransportControls`. Here is the introduction:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls